# How to pass parameter to data provider in testng from csv file

Tags: java, csv, testng, test-data, testng-dataprovider

Am reading data from csv file ,  i have test for which this data will be the input . 
i want it to run as tescase for every set of value. for that am using data provider 
The problem is , it is taking only the last set row of data , please help me in debugging the code

```
For eg : if my csv has following data 
name1 id1 text1
name2 id2 text2
name3 id3 text3
```

it taking only last row name3 id3 text3 and running the test only once not three times.

```
 @DataProvider(name = "test")
        public Object[][] provider( ) throws InterruptedException
        {

            Object[][] returnObject ;

            String[] checkpoint = ReadfromCSV();

            count = count + 1;

            returnObject = new Object[][]{checkpoint };
            return returnObject;
        }

        @Test(description = "Test", groups =  "test" , dataProvider = "test")
        public void compare(String val1,String val2,String val3,String val4,String val5,String val6,String val7,String val8,String val9,String val10,String val11 ) {

            System.out.println("1:" + val1);

            System.out.println("4:" + val2);

            System.out.println("5:" + val3);


        }
        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        public String[] ReadfromCSV() throws InterruptedException {


            String[] data= null;
            String csvFile = "F:/sample1.csv";
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line = "";
            String cvsSplitBy = ",";

            try {

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    // use comma as separator
                data= line.split(cvsSplitBy);




                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Done");
            return data;


        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should read entire file in data provider and return iterator of test cases. Here is some pseudocode for data provider.  Notice that I used `List<String []>` to store test cases instead of `Object[][]`.  This allows you do define test cases dynamically.

```
    @DataProvider(name = "test")
    public Iterator<Object []> provider( ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        List<Object []> testCases = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] data= null;

        //this loop is pseudo code
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // use comma as separator
            data= line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            testCases.add(data);
        }

        return testCases.iterator();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , Am not getting your idea . Can u make changes in my code and show .

Comment: @Dude I updated my answer. I suspect that you missed the fact that TestNg calls data provider only once to prepare various test cases for multiple test runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[][] ReadfromCSV() throws InterruptedException {

    int count =0;
    String[] data= null;
    String returnObj[][] = null; 
    
    //System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    String csvFile = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/src/test/resources/testdata.csv";
            
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        //this loop is pseudo code
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        int datalength = 0;
        int listsize =0;;
        
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // use comma as separator

            content.add(line);
        }
        System.out.println(content);
        
        listsize = content.size();
        datalength = content.get(0).split(cvsSplitBy).length;
        returnObj = new String[listsize][datalength];
        
        for (int i = 0; i<listsize; i++) {
            
            data = content.get(i).split(cvsSplitBy);
            for (int j=0; j< datalength ; j++) {
                returnObj[i][j] = data[j];
                
            }
            
        }
        

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
    return returnObj;

}}
```