# how to use a csv file in a selenium script

Tags: csv, selenium, selenium-webdriver, parameterized

I need to feed my test with testdata from a .csv file and therefore I need to parameterize my test. How is that done in Selenium?

Here is the code:

```
element.sendKeys("30097429029");
```

I want the numbers to be parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Selenium related, you could use some lib for .csv handling (or something like this https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/) and than pass this data to your methods. Not sure what is exactly a problem, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to use unique users per browser in a Selenium Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Data from csv can be passed using Dataproviders. A Data Provider is a method annotated with @DataProvider. A Data Provider returns an array of objects. More detailed answer you can find [How to pass parameter to data provider in testng from csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033985/how-to-pass-parameter-to-data-provider-in-testng-from-csv-file)